# Game ticks getting slower when rendering canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, class, canvas, game-development

I'm trying to run this snake game in javascript with html canvas module, so I created a Game logic inspired from java.
This is the website for the project ( deployed on github pages ) : [View Websie](https://ayoubachak.github.io/web-snake-game/)
You can check the code on :  [Code](https://github.com/ayoubachak/web-snake-game)

---

The main file that has the logic for the game is Game.js
every game class (Game.js, Snake.js, SnakeCell.js, Map.js and Food.js ) has a render method that renders it in the canvas in the index.html

The issue is that it get's slower and slower on every tick.
I checked with a time function to see if the rendering is taking time but mostly it doesn't surpass 2ms

```
// rendering the game
this.render();
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    let now = Date.now();
    that.tick()
    console.log(Date.now() - now);
}, this.gameTick);
```

`
and I have some array manipulation so I had to test if any of the snake structure is causing the slowness, all the snake body is stored in an attribute body on the snake object which is an array of snake cells

```
let daba = Date.now();
newBody.unshift(newHead)
console.log(Date.now() - daba);
if(removeTail){
    newBody.pop()
}
console.log(daba)
```

Please don't hate on me because I'm still a beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: There's no way to know from the context provided--it could be almost anything. I'd sanity-check that event handlers aren't adding event handlers w/o any conditionals or removal *(e.g., an exponential event handler explosion)*.

Comment: is there any way to solve this then ? or at least redoing it in a more performant way?

Comment: *it get's slower and slower on every tick* - do you measure that in some way or you know just by looking?

Comment: not exactly the ticks because when I measure I find that there is not lag in the tics, but you can try the game [here](https://ayoubachak.github.io/web-snake-game/), hit the start button and try playing for some time.. it will lag a lot.

Comment: Sure, but there’s no way to guess what the problem might be.